# Transparent triangle over a menu item

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I do something like that?

[Picture http://i6.pixs.ru/storage/1/5/3/SnimokPNG_6031795_12562153.png](http://i6.pixs.ru/storage/1/5/3/SnimokPNG_6031795_12562153.png)

If `:hover` or `:active` the triangle appears and makes the background visible.

Comment: Please post your code that you tried.

Comment: I think you would either have to use SVG or cut a png mask for this..

Comment: and if the different background in a different menu items? sorry for my english

Comment: Thorsten  i have no idea how i can do that. Idea only with pictures, but i want try to do only with css )

Comment: with a  pseudo element or an extra element you may do something close and add transition too : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bKokd hover the white box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a pseudo element or an inline-block element to draw a rotated square, with a hudge box shadow, this color stands outside it in order to fill its parent.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bKokd)**

---

HTML demo

```
<div>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p> whatever next</p>
</div>
```

---

CSS demo

```
body {/* bg for demo to show transparency */
  background:linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,5), rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,5), rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,5), rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,5), rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,5), rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,5), rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,5), rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,5), rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,5)) yellow
}
div {
  margin:2em;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2000px white;
  margin-top:-20px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
div * {
  position:relative;/* bring everything back on top of pseudo */
}
/* change bg color */
div:hover:before {
    box-shadow:0 0 0 2000px turquoise;
}
```

Comment: the trick of using box-shadow here is interesting but its limitation is the element can only have solid background (not image or gradient). However it's useful in case we just need solid background.

Comment: @KingKing Unless you play with absolute position and then use border-image, but then you make it really difficult to maintain , tune and loose some browser compatibility

Comment: there is at least another way without using border-image, however it's complicated (not easy to maintain).

Comment: @KingKing oh god , you make me curious !!

Comment: @GCyrillus here is a demo allowing the button to have gradient/image background http://jsfiddle.net/zw99K/6/ . It works best on ***IE11***, looks like transforming in IE11 is so perfect. Also it works worst on the so-called ***FireFox***, there may be some trick to eliminate the issue on FireFox. The demo is probably just one of ways based on the same mechanism (`overflow:hidden`, transforming, ...), it may be tweaked more to work better but it's good enough to show the idea (that made you curious).

Comment: @KingKing thanks for the demo, it's indeed a lot of work to tweak. great job !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS-only approach: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9UQg/1/). (This example uses a square .jpg image for demonstration purposes only - you would replace this with a .png of your triangle.)

Here are the salient points, making the assumption that the triangle is an image file, and being attached to the `<a>` tag**:

```
a {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

a:hover:before, a:focus:before {
    content: '';
    width: 16px; /* same as image width */
    height:16px; /* same as image height */
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/16/16/') center center no-repeat;  
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 40%; /* adjust according to your design */
}
```

If the width of the `<a>` tags are set in px/em, this will affect the value of the `left` rule in the `:before` styling

** I've seen some people attempt this sort of thing with images or styles attached to the `<li>` tag wrapped around the `<a>`, but I prefer to change the styling of the element being targeted.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a css hover selector where you are changing the background image.

```
mydiv:hover
{ 
background-image:url('mytraingle.png');
}
```

There are a million ways to answer you question, but i would play around with this CSS selector first. Maybe this is all you need.